# Run VB.NET Project in Windows Server

Tags: vb.net, server

I try to build application for windows server . 
when i try run this application in my pc (windows 8.1) successfully
[Runing in PC](http://prntscr.com/7rjv7o)

When i try to run this application in my server (windows server 2008 R2) it's error.
[Runing in Server](http://prntscr.com/7rjvo9)

i think my application is not compatible with windows server.
but i don't know how to fix it ...

anyone can help me to fix it?

Comment: Did you press that _View Problem Details_ ? If yes what they have to say about your app?

Comment: view problem -> (http://prntscr.com/7rjz6t)  (http://prntscr.com/7rjzpu)     (http://prntscr.com/7rk00k) and i don't know how to fix it

Comment: I've noticed that sometimes not using Val() when working with a number value will work on one PC and not another. Could it be a problem on a Date / Time / Currency / ETC value. The regional settings may be different on your PC to the server. Also, check that all your DLLs are there and you are using the same .NET framework on both your PC and the server.

Comment: The screen shot that you provided only shows what you have stated, that protection.exe has stopped working. Maybe if you expand the details tab on that message and copy/paste it's contents on here.

Comment: Is the program compiled for 32 or 64 bits?  You are getting an invalid operation exception which might indicate that some of the support DLLs are missing.  Also, is the .Net framework that your application is compiled for the same level that is on your server?  One of the easiest ways of making sure that all conditions are met is to use a Setup project, which will check versions and do other necessary work.